# What is the issue here ? i have already installed geopandas and folium from pip install command from powershell

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, data-science, visualization

I was getting ready to perform a EDA on Tsunami Data as I was importing the following module geopandas module gave the error of not found so i installed it from the powershell by using pip but then too the error persisted and the same is happening with the folium too.

```
import os, math
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import geopandas as gpd

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
sns.set_style("darkgrid")

import folium
from folium import Choropleth, Circle, Marker
from folium.plugins import HeatMap, MarkerCluster

here is the error 
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
~\AppData\Local\Temp\ipykernel_9832\21392064.py in <module>
      2 import numpy as np
      3 import pandas as pd
----> 4 import geopandas as gpd
      5 
      6 import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'geopandas'
enter image description here
```

I was simply expecting it to work totally fine  i previously worked on this same system with several modules there was no error of such types.

Comment: It migh not be installed in your virtual environment. try to run the pip install command in notebook that you use. You can run windows commands by adding "!" to front of the line in jupyter. Like: "!pip install geopandas"

Comment: done that too it is already showing requirements already satisfied.

Comment: do `source /env/script/activate`

Comment: then install using pip

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

enter the virtual env and then do the installation of the packages

```bash
source /env/script/activate
pip install %NAMEHERE%
```